# Generating a JSON doc with envelope/header using Gson

Tags: java, json, gson

I use Gson to generate JSON from a `List<Users>`. I'd like to generate a JSON doc with a header/body structure, something like:

```
{
  "count" : 15,
  "users" : [
    {
      "userId" : 149,
      "userName" : "jack0231",
      "displayName" : "Jackie"
    },
    {
      "userId" : 301,
      "userName" : "helms_mighty",
      "displayName" : "Hippoman"
    }
...
  ]
}
```

Currently I'm just writing out the structure myself like this:

```
StringBuilder jsonResp = new StringBuilder();
jsonResp.append("{\"count\":"+users.size()+",");
jsonResp.append("\"users\":");
Gson gs = new Gson();
jsonResp.append(gs.toJson(users));
jsonResp.append("}");
```

Is there a better/built-in way of doing this? Thanks!

Comment: Not related to your question, but use either a `StringBuilder` *or* string concatenation with `+=`, not *both*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what you need. If you put your list inside another (simple) class, you can serialize correctly in one step avoiding all the boilerplate of the StringBuilder. You can run directly this example.

```
package stackoverflow.questions.q19966529;

import java.util.*;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class Q19966529 {

    public static class User{
        Long userId;
        String userName;
        String displayName;

        public User(Long userId, String userName, String displayName){
            this.userId = userId;
            this.userName = userName;
            this.displayName = displayName;             
        }
    }

    public static class UserList{
        private List<User> list = new ArrayList<>(); //java 7 
        private int count = 0;

        public void addUser(User u){
            list.add(u);
            count = list.size();

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        UserList ul = new UserList();
        ul.addUser(new User(149L, "jack0231", "Jackie"));
        ul.addUser(new User(301L, "helms_mighty", "Hippoman"));

        String json = new Gson().toJson(ul);
        System.out.println(json);
    }

}
```

and this is the result:

```
{"list":[{"userId":149,"userName":"jack0231","displayName":"Jackie"},{"userId":301,"userName":"helms_mighty","displayName":"Hippoman"}],"count":2}
```

To see it formatted like your example, you need an external formatter like [this](http://json.parser.online.fr/)

Comment: Ugh. I guess that works. Maybe I should subclass Gson, that would work too. Your answer would work, so I'll accept it as the answer. Thanks very much for posting an answer!

Answer (score 0):

How about making a `SerializedUsers` class, add a field for the count data, and a field for the users list. Than serialized this class.